# Server-side infinite scroll with ngRx in agGrid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ngrx, ngrx-store, ag-grid-angular

I need to implement an infinite scroll for ag-Grid but I cannot make it work with the ngRx state.

There is a GET endpoint that returns cars. Let's assume that the endpoint returns hundreds of thousands of rows. I used the JSON server for that which you can see here: https://my-json-server.typicode.com/syzmon9/cars-db
The endpoint has some offset parameter: `https://my-json-server.typicode.com/syzmon9/cars-db/cars_{offset}`

I'm using the newest ag-grid and my component looks like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(AgGridAngular, {
    static: true
  }) agGrid: AgGridAngular;

  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [{
    field: 'name'
  }, {
    field: 'type'
  }];
  public rowData: any[] | null = [];
  public gridOptions: GridOptions;

  private infiniteScrollDataSource: IDatasource;

  constructor(
    private store: Store < CarsState > ,
    private apiService: CarsApiService
  ) {
    this.store.dispatch(loadCars({
      limit: 30,
      offset: 0
    }));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions = {
      ...this.gridOptions,
      rowModelType: 'serverSide',
      cacheBlockSize: 30,
      infiniteInitialRowCount: 30,
    };

    // this.infiniteScrollDataSource = {
    //   getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
    //     this.apiService.loadCars(params.startRow).subscribe((data) => {
    //       console.log(params.startRow);
    //       const totalCount = 90;
    //       const lastRow = params.endRow >= totalCount ? totalCount : -1;
    //       params.successCallback(data, lastRow);
    //     });
    //   },
    // };
  }

  onGridReady($event) {
    const dataSource = this.createServerSideDatasource();
    this.agGrid ? .api ? .setServerSideDatasource(dataSource);
  }

  private createServerSideDatasource(): IServerSideDatasource {
    return {
      getRows: (params) => {
        console.log(
          '[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: startRow = ' +
          params.request.startRow +
          ', endRow = ' +
          params.request.endRow
        );
        // get data for request from our fake server
        var response = this.apiService
          .loadCars(params.request.startRow)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            params.success({
              rowData: data,
              rowCount: 90, // total count
            });
          });
      },
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [serverSideInfiniteScroll]="true"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Now it's working with simple API calls using HttpClient but I want to use the ngRx effects to retrieve the data:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CarsEffects {
  loadCars$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(loadCars),
      switchMap((action) =>
        this.apiService.loadCars(action.offset).pipe(
          tap((cars) => {
            console.log(cars);
          }),
          // some other mapping or data manipulation here
          map(
            (cars) => loadCarsSuccess({ cars }),
            catchError((error) => {
              return of(loadCarsFailed({ error }));
            })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions: Actions,
    private apiService: CarsApiService,
    private store: Store<CarsState>,
    private helperService: HelperService
  ) {}
}
```

So I need to dispatch the `getCarsStarted` action instead of calling the `HttpClient.get` and make the infinite scroll work. Any ideas on how to do it? I've tried different approaches such as using selectors, using external helperService with behaviorSubject but there is always an issue. Sometimes it's the infinite loop between `store.select` and `store.dispatch`, sometimes the rows for grid are duplicated instead lodaing the new ones. I feel like I stucked with that and have no other ideas how to resolve that.

I've created a stackblitz working example with a simple HTTP call instead of using the ngRx state:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/server-side-inf-scroll

Comment: considering this problem myself. ag-grid has its own cache which it uses when scrolling back upwards to rows which were previously loaded, so I am not sure whether that makes it impractical to use NgRx to manage row state. there could be concurrent requests which could come back at different times, and which may then become stale and wouldn't be a representation of the grid anyway.